# why does count(*) return 0 even if there are results?

Tags: mysql

Recently I had tried to make a stored procedure in mySQL, but I don't understand many things and now I would like to know why, when I execute this procedure, resultat is equal to 0, even if there are more than a hundred results?
Here is the procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test4`(out resultat int)
begin
select value, timestamp 
from sensorParser 
where sensor='SOILTC' 
and id_wasp='SPARK_SA'  ;
select resultat=count(*);
end
```

If you know, could you explain it to me clearly ?

I changed it this way :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test4`(out resultat int)
begin
select value, timestamp, resultat=count(* ) from sensorParser 
where sensor='SOILTC'
and id_wasp='SPARK_SA'  ;
end
```

but it still doesn't work, it shows only one result which is:

```
value = 19.437
timestamp = 2019-02-04 07:40:06
resultat=count(*) = NULL
```

Comment: You didn't select the count to be a count of anything - there's no from clause in your second query. And it has no relationship to the first query, if that's what you're wondering

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 queries in your stored procedure.

First one seem good (we don't have table definition nor data sample to validate it).

Second query `select resultat=count(*);` is not good, there is no from clause.  count(*) from nothing is 0!

Note `;` is end query delimiter.

**Try this to got both all values and count**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test4`(out resultat int)
begin
select value, timestamp from sensorParser 
where sensor='SOILTC'
and id_wasp='SPARK_SA'  ;

select count(*) into resultat from sensorParser 
where sensor='SOILTC'
and id_wasp='SPARK_SA'  ;

end
```

And, when calling your stored procedure :

```
call test4(@resultat);
select @resultat;
```

Comment: I updated my code could you take a look to it please, it still doesn't work

Comment: And for the delimiter, I know that ; is the default one but I changed it when I created the procedure, that way it execute all the queries

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting for.  You need value and timestamp, count, or both of them?